# Query cosmos db siblings with no childs

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to query cosmos db without returning child? I want following result:

```
[{"groupId":1,"name":"group1"},{"groupId":2,"name":"group2"}]
```

From following:

```
{
    "groups":
    [
        {
            "groupId":1,
            "name":"group1",
            "subgroups":
            [
                {
                    "subGroupId":1,
                    "name":"subgroup1"
                },
                {
                    "subGroupId":2,
                    "name":"subgroup2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "groupId":2,
            "name":"group2",
            "subgroups":
            [
                {
                    "subGroupId":1,
                    "name":"subgroup1"
                },
                {
                    "subGroupId":2,
                    "name":"subgroup2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would prefer it without trigger so pure select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use join keyword :

```
SELECT g.groupId,g.name FROM c
join g in c.groups
```

Output:

[image]